# Trying to create an 8x8 chessboard in a console application

Tags: vb.net, console-application

```
Dim chessboard(7, 7) As Integer 

For i = 0 To chessboard.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j = 0 To chessboard.GetUpperBound(0)
        If (i + j) mod 2 = Then
            Console.out.Write(chessboard(i, j) = "B")
        Else
            Console.out.WriteLine(chessboard(i,j)="W")
        End If      
    Next
Next

Console.in.ReadLine()
```

Comment: And the question isssss... * Drumroll *

Comment: What is that language anyway? Java Basic .NET? -- Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: im trying to create an 8x8 chessboard on VB console and it won't work

Comment: _"it won't work"_ represents an infinite amount of possible problems. You need to be more specific. Start by reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you just started coding in VB.NET recently I recommend you follow a tutorial describing the language structure. Microsoft has a pretty good one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk24xdbe(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I would suggest you start by drawing 1 cell, when that works do one row and only after try to do the whole board.

Comment: @VisualVincent - Actually, `Console.Out.Write` and `Console.In.ReadLine` are valid methods.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway : Well I'll be damned, you're right! One really does learn something new every day (at least on Stack Overflow ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are new at this...

```
    Dim chessboard(7, 7) As String

    For i As Integer = 0 To chessboard.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j As Integer = 0 To chessboard.GetUpperBound(1)
            If ((i + j) And 1) = 0 Then
                chessboard(i, j) = "B"
                Console.Write(chessboard(i, j))
            Else
                chessboard(i, j) = "W"
                Console.Write(chessboard(i, j))
            End If
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("")
    Next
```